# MySQL INSERT/UPDATE on POINT column

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, spatial, mysql-error-1416

I'm trying to populate my DB with geographical places of my country. One of my tables have 4 fields: ID[PK], latitude. longitude ande geoPoint

```
EDIT `SCDBs`.`Punto_Geografico`;

SET @lat = 18.469692;

SET @lon = -63.93212;

SET @g = 'POINT(@lat @lon)';

UPDATE Punto_Geografico SET latitude = @lat, longitude =@lon, geoPoint =@g WHERE idpunto_geografico = 0;
```

im getting the following error:
Error Code: 1416
Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

I'm pretty sure that 'geoPoint' field is a POINT field with a spatial index. Am i missing anything.14

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try doing it without assigning your values to server values. Especially if they contain function calls. MySQL treats the contents of the variables as plain text and won't see that there's a function call in there.

```
UPDATE ... SET latitude=18, longitute=-63, geoPoint=POINT(18 -63) WHERE ...
```

Comment: For some reason:
UPDATE Punto_Geografico SET latitude = 18.469692, longitude = -63.93212, geoPoint =PoinT(18.469692, -63.93212) WHERE idpunto_geografico = 0;

It says that it was succesful updating but i dont see any values in the geoPoint Column. Also i did a "," inside the POINT statement only way that worked.

Comment: Apparently in MySQL I cannot see what's inside the geometry column however if i use SELECT AsText(*) ... i can see point information.

Comment: This doesn't work, the answer by FattyPotatoes is correct. The POINT() needs to be represented as a string and wrapped with the GeomFromText() function.

Comment: This is correct since MySQL 5.1.35, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33454/2725

Comment: I test following and it works for me: `UPDATE ... SET latitude=18, longitute=-63, geoPoint=POINT(18, -63) WHERE ...`. I separate two argument of POINT with comma.

Comment: Please update `POINT` params needs to be comma separated according to [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-point-property-functions.html)

Comment: This answer must be edited. POINT(-63 18), instead of POINT(18 -63). Latitude should be stored as Y, and X for longitude.

Answer (score 13):

You need to use this syntax:

```
UPDATE ... SET latitude=18, longitute=-63, geoPoint=GeomFromText('POINT(18 -63)') WHERE ...
```

Comment: This was only needed in MySQL < 5.1.35, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33454/2725 - the accepted answer is correct.

Comment: It also works: `UPDATE ... SET latitude=18, longitute=-63, geoPoint=POINT(18, -63) WHERE ...`. Separate arguments in POINT by comma

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO users (name, homeLocation)
    VALUES
    ("John",  POINT(25.7786222, -80.1956483) ),
    ("Anna",  POINT(23.7786222, -81.1956483) )
```