# Cannot insert GeomFromText('POINT(..)') in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, geometry, geospatial

I've created a database where one of the tables stores the geolocation of some points.
I'm trying to fill that table, which a priori seems pretty easy with `GeomFromText('POINT(39.48280 -0.34804)')`, but it doesn't work. All the other columns, like id, name... do get their values, but the location column remains empty.

So then I try to update the row I've just added with:

```
UPDATE `pfc_db`.`poi`
SET
`location` = GeomFromText('POINT(39.48280 -0.34804)')
WHERE id = 'poi00001';
```

And MySQLWorkbench shows its output:

```
0 row(s) affected
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Why does it find the row it has to update but doesn't do it? If I try to update another column it works perfect, but not with the location.

I've been googling for a solution, I've found posts like [MySQL INSERT/UPDATE on POINT column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293062/mysql-insert-update-on-point-column) and I've tried the proposed solutions but still nothing.

So, anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: No one? Really? Please, I need help with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "remains empty"? Can you query that column and for instance retrieve the x coordinate?

Comment: Consider asking a moderator to migrate the question to gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but the MySQLWorkbench GUI didn't display the Point variables, at least in my computer.

Then I tried to query the DB from a php script and it printed the Points perfectly, so the DB actually stored them. It was just a GUI display problem. Should I report it as a bug to MySQL?