# Polygon data not getting inserted in MySQL

Tags: mysql, polygon, geospatial, spatial

I am trying to insert spatial data in MySQL using the following statement but even though query is executed successfully, the table does not show any data.

**Table Name : geo
Column name : g** type : Geometry

Query:

SET @g = 'POLYGON((72.79230192816932
18.94774395435967,72.79227877224074 18.94774197280634,72.79228473707543 18.94767850389454,72.79230789299416 18.94768048544693,72.79230192816932 18.94774395435967))';

```
INSERT INTO geom(g)VALUES (GEOMFROMTEXT(@g));
```

AS you can see polygon is closed, still table does not show anything.
I tried even POLYFROMTEXT but even that is giving the same output.

I intend to check whether a point lie inside this polygon or not. But the polygon itself is not getting inserted. 
Please advise as I am new to Spatial in MySQL. **MySQL version : 5.6.21**

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144053/cannot-insert-geomfromtextpoint-in-mysql, may be you are also having the same problem highlighted here.

Comment: works fine for me using the command line client ... so it would indeed be interesting to know what client you are using

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query, though you say your table is called geo and you are inserting into geom.

Comment: That was a typo.. Actually seems like there's a bug with SQLYog.. The data is getting inserted into the MySQL properly but SQLYog still shows it blank. I checked data from MYSQL prompt and it was present.. The link provided by akfkmupiwu actually helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug with SQLYog GUI. The data is getting inserted into the

> MYSQL

properly but

> SQLYog

does not show the same.

Had to manually check from the mysql command prompt. The data was indeed present in the database.

**If the query fired is incorrect, then SQLyog will show NULL in rows.. However when correct query is fired, it will show BLANK.**